# Selecting from the same table twice with results on the same line

Tags: mysql, join

I want to generate a monthly report of total payments received from clients and total sent to suppliers in a single mySQL query that return these two totals on the same line. I can do it with UNION but that returns the results on different rows. All payments are in a `payments` table with the basic structure:

```
id | id_order | id_contact | amount | date_time
```

**Update:**
`contact_id` can be either client or supplier. The related `contacts` table has a field `contact_type`which is either "SUP" or "CLI".

I would like the result to sum up all the payments received from clients and sent to suppliers during a time frame so I can generate the profit based on actual payments not the theoretical profit based on order sale price - my cost, especially because these orders are paid in installments over a long period of time so showing $5000 profit in June for an order placed in June is not relevant as long as the order is being paid 3000 in August and another 2000 in December.

```
Month      | total $ sent to suppliers | total $ received from clients
June 2014    3000                        5000
July 2014    2500                        3800
```

Other supporting tables that I have are the "orders" table, the "contacts" table. Is there a way to do this with joins? Is this possible and OK performance wise and if not what other options do I have? (I am using MySQL 5.5 and will do this in PHP, if it matters)

Comment: what sql have you tried?

Comment: I tried a UNION (select total payments from client UNION select payments from suppliers)but that returns two rows in the result and I'd like two columns. SQL is not my strong point :)

Comment: what determines if it was received or sent?  can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I updated the question. `contact_id` can be either client or supplier. The related `contacts` table has a field `contact_type` which is either "SUP" or "CLI".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use conditional aggregation.  You don't provide key information, such as how you know whether someone is a supplier or client.  The following is a sketch of what the query would look like:

```
select date_format(date_time, '%M %Y') as month,
       sum(case when contact_id = "supplier" then amount else 0 end) as sent,
       sum(case when contact_id = "client" then amount else 0 end) as received
from table t
group by date_format(date_time, '%M %Y')
order by min(date_time);
```

Note the `order by`.  Because you are using a non-standard date format, this will still ensure that the rows are in temporal order.

Comment: in the "contacts" table i have a column contact_type with CLI(ent) or SUP(lier)

Comment: @LavaRo . . . Just plug the appropriate logic into the `when` condition.

Comment: I thought this site was for answers not suggestions :) Sorry, I don't know what would be the appropriate logic :) SQL is not my strong point but I will update the question

Comment: I figure it out, it was logical, and your answer definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, based on @Gordon Linoff answer

```
select date_format(p.pay_dcreated, '%M %Y') as month,
sum(case when c.type_con = "FAC" then p.pay_amount else 0 end) as sent,
sum(case when c.type_con = "CST" then p.pay_amount else 0 end) as received
from payments_pay as p, contacts_con as c
where  p.pay_idcon=c.id_con
group by date_format(p.pay_dcreated, '%M %Y')
order by min(p.pay_dcreated);
```

This gives me a result I wanted.